# A Datatype to represent Sonar/Radar/Echo Location

Tags: java, c#, c, types

I was just having a general think about sonar equipment. How could the sonar results be represented in a `datatype`.

At the moment the solution I have came up with was to have a 360 2D `array` with values suggesting the distance to when something has been hit, with a max range implying nothing was there. The problem with this is that it becomes work intensive with a 3d sonar example and isn't too cheap with 2d either.

Note: *I want a `datatype` to represent active sonar.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several representations for range-finder data.  Depending on what processing you're doing, one of them may help you decrease the cost of processing.

#### Polar coordinates, skipping missing values

Instead of setting missing values to MAX_RANGE, store only the hits in polar coordinates.  In C, you would use an array of this struct:

```
struct Hit {
  float angle;
  float range;
  float incline;  // If you need 3d coordinates.
}
```

The benefit of this representation is that you don't spend time processing missing readings.  The downside is that polar coordinates can be difficult to work with directly, leading me to...

#### Cartesian coordinates, skipping missing values

Cartesian coordinates are often easier to handle.  Use an array of this struct:

```
struct Point {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
}
```

#### A kd-tree

A kd-tree is a data structure that partitions space in a way that makes it easy to answer common queries more quickly.  Queries like "What points are 5 meters from (x,y,z)" or "What is the closest point to (x,y,z)", can be answered much more quickly with a kd-tree than by iterating through every point individually.

#### An octree (or quadtree, in 2d)

An octree is very similar to a kd-tree, but chooses a different method of partitioning space (The kd-tree partitions space by ensuring the points are divided into equal groups, while the octree partitions space just by taking the midpoint).  If you're adding and removing points frequently, it's much easier to use an octree.  Octrees work less well when your points are very unevenly distributed--if you're working with a space of 1 km, and have two points 1 nm apart, the octree will be less efficient than a kd-tree.

### Conclusion

Those are the major representations of range-finder data.  One of those may work for your situation, but you should understand that any of these representations could lead to slow processing.  Each type of processing may have a different representation that would be most optimal.  If your processing is still too slow, you should ask a question about the specific type of processing that you're doing.

Comment: Thank you, very impressive understanding you have. I wanted to get away from using a simple array so will look into the tree formats suggested. Thanks again.